# Is merging pages allowed in mmap?

Tags: c, mmap

In short I want to resize memory but have the old memory in the middle of the new.

So what I did was use `mmap` for the initial size (`p1`), `mmap` at an address before `p1` to pretend I made the memory bigger, then treat the new pointer as if I created it with a single `mmap` (`p3`, `mremap`). The code seems to work but I'm not sure if this is what I should be doing. If it isn't how should I create more memory and have the old/current memory be in the middle of it?

```
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
#include <cassert>
#include <cerrno>
int main()
{
    auto p1 = (char*) mmap(0, 4096, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_PRIVATE, -1, 0);
    if (!p1 || p1==(char*)-1)
        return -1;

    auto p1_32 = (int *)p1;
    memset(p1, 0, 4096);
    p1_32[5] = 1035;

    auto p2 = mmap(p1-4096, 4096, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_FIXED, -1, 0);
    if (!p2 || p2==(void*)-1)
        return -2;

    auto p2_32 = (int *)p2;
    memset(p2, 0, 4096);
    p2_32[5] = 5301;

    assert(p2_32[1024+5] == 1035);

    auto p3 = mremap(p2, 4096*2, 4096*4, MREMAP_MAYMOVE);
    if (p3==(char*)-1)
    {
        printf("Errno %d\n", errno);
        return -2;
    }
    auto p3_32 = (int*)p3;

    assert(p3_32[5] == 5301);
    assert(p3_32[1024+5] == 1035);

    printf("Is this correct?\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Few notes: 1) you don't have to zero-out memory returned with `mmap` - it is already zero-initialized (otherwise it could leak sensitive information from another process). 2) I think you should tag this with `linux` since `mremap` is not available on some OSes.

Comment: @StaceyGirl I do not think that the memory is really guaranteed to be zero-filled. The system takes measures to avoid leaking sensitive information, this is correct, but this does not necessarily mean that the pages contain zeroes. Perhaps previously mapped pages of the same process can be reused

Comment: @StaceyGirl But the `memset()` calls will force the actual assignment of physical memory to the virtual address.  Those mappings are not created until the memory is actually accessed, and deferring those mappings can cause serious performance issues for time-critical processing if that processing stalls because the kernel has to actually create the memory pages.

Comment: @Ctx In this case spec requires memory to be filled with zeroes (if man pages can be called spec).  There is `MAP_UNINITIALIZED ` for embedded system though.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I don't think this matters in this case. If page faults need to be avoided, there is `MAP_POPULATE` specifically for this - which will do this faster.

Comment: @StaceyGirl Hm, this manpage apparently does not specify that the pages are zeroed out: https://linux.die.net/man/3/mmap

Comment: @StaceyGirl `MAP_POPULATE` is non-standard.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Neither is `MAP_ANONYMOUS`.

Comment: @AndrewHenle But `mlock()` is probably more appropriate for that purpose.

Comment: Note that the memory just before and just after your mapping might already be used.

Comment: @Ctx `mlock()` can require elevated privileges.

Comment: @AndrewHenle But `memset()` does not guarantee that the pages are still in memory in the next microsecond, so I think, it wouldn't be more than a hack to use it for time-critical processing

Comment: @Ctx Time-critical processing is properly done on a system that has known-to-be-sufficient resources by processes that don't oversubscribe those resources.

Comment: @Ctx: That man page doesn't even describe mapping anonymous memory, which is the only time zero-filling comes up. Otherwise, you're mapping *something*, which means you wouldn't get zeroes, you'd get whatever was in that file, object, what-have-you. On Linux, `mmap` is implemented as copy-on-write mappings of the zero page.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Yes, but you have to tell the system, how to use these resources, specifically, which pages are to reside in memory and which are not. `mlock()` and `mlockall()` is used for this task.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Correct, this is how it is currently implemented. But this does not mean, that it may not change in the future or differ on other systems, so it is probably bad to rely on the specific current behaviour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As described [here](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/mmap.html)

> The `munmap()` function shall remove any mappings for those entire pages
>   containing any part of the address space of the process starting at
>   `addr` and continuing for `len` bytes.

so it is allowed to remove multiple mappings with a single `munmap` call (as if it was a single mapping).

There is a problem with your code though: how do you know if a page (`p2`) before your page (`p1`) is not used? It could be already allocated by other pars of the program (including `malloc`), by using `MAP_FIXED` like this you will rewrite (remap) its content:

> When `MAP_FIXED` is set in the flags argument, the implementation is
>   informed that the value of pa shall be `addr`, exactly. If `MAP_FIXED` is
>   set, `mmap()` may return `MAP_FAILED` and set `errno` to `[EINVAL]`. If a
>   `MAP_FIXED` request is successful, the mapping established by `mmap()`
>   replaces any previous mappings for the process' pages in the range
>   `[pa,pa+len)`.

So I don't think this trick can be useful in the general case, you should use `mremap` instead.

As for how this is implemented: Linux does merge sequential private anonymous mappings, so both will be merged into a single `vma_struct` in the kernel. This "feature" has undesirable side effects such as [`munmap` failing to free memory with `ENOMEM`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43743555/munmap-failure-with-enomem-with-private-anonymous-mapping). But this is more of an implementation detail, not something you have control over.

Comment: I figured I'd have to write more logic to make sure p1 and p2 connect. How would I implement this using mremap? I don't see a way to specify where the old contents should be.

Comment: I have another idea how to implement this. I could use `mremap` to move it into a larger location, then immediately remap it within itself + mmap the space before it. Although I'm not sure if mremap-ping into itself is legal

Comment: @EricStotch You can try to a specific address without `MAP_FIXED`, this will act as a hint: a kernel will map data there only if there is no mapping in place. `mremap` with address will do the same thing - it won't work for your case. You can try file mappings instead, but instead of file you can use a pseudo file returned by `memfd_create` - such file allows you to preserve data even after unmapping and remapping it.